# Is there an elegant way to prevent click of ancestor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement that table rows are clickable. I implemented that by changing the cursor on hover in CSS, and by implementing a click event on the table row, which goes to the link specified in a `data-href` attribute.

The thing is, there are some buttons inside of table rows, which trigger an AJAX request. So, when I click on those buttons, I want the click event on the parent row to be prevented.

This is my current implementation (in CoffeeScript):

```
jQuery.fn.preventClick     = -> $(@).data("disabled", true)
jQuery.fn.isClickPrevented = -> $(@).data("disabled")
jQuery.fn.enableClick      = -> $(@).removeData("disabled")

$("#table tr").click ->
  window.location = $(@).data("href") unless $(@).isClickPrevented()
  $(@).enableClick()

$("#table tr").on "click", "[data-remote='true']", ->
  $(@).closest("tr").preventClick()
```

I'm relying on the fact that the child click event gets triggered before the parent one.

For me this looks way too complicated. Is there a more elegant way to implement this?

Comment: `stopPropagation()` ?

Comment: There's also `isDefaultPrevented()`.

Comment: `stopPropagation` + (optionaly) [capturing the event](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)...

Comment: jQuery (at least < 2.0) doesn't have a way to specify useCapture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your event handler, you can prevent an event bubbling up to the ancestors by calling

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

(You'll need to accept `e` as the first argument of the event handler function.)

You can also do `return false` from an event handler, which does both `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`.

Comment: That's it! :) I'm fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery, so this was a great help. I will accept your answer when StackOverflow's minimum 10 minutes pass.